# Verbes pronominaux qui n’entraînent pas d'accord du participe passé

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, usage, verbes-pronominaux

J’aimerais savoir s’ils existe des verbes comme *se téléphoner*, *se succéder* (sans accord du participe passé)

- Se téléphoner → nous nous sommes téléphon**é**.
- Se succéder → nous nous sommes succéd**é**.

  Par contre
- s’accrocher → nous nous sommes accroch**és**

Comment: Je pense que tu veux dire « accorder » plutôt que « conjuguer », non ?

Comment: C'est soit « téléphoner à quelqu'un », soit « se téléphoner » mais pas « se téléphoner à ».

Comment: @Toto merci c’est ça que je voulais dire

Comment: http://bescherelle.ca/participes-passes-verbes-pronominaux/

Answer (score 2):

- Si le verbe est précédé par un complément direct, qu'il s'agisse du pronom ou pas, il y a accord
- Si le verbe est seulement précédé par un complément indirect, il n'y a pas d'accord (téléphoner à => elles se sont téléphoné)
- Si le pronom ne peut pas être identifié comme complément direct ou indirect, il y a accord : suicider quelqu'un (compl. direct) n'a pas de sens, suicider à quelqu'un (compl. indirect) n'en a pas non plus => elles se sont suicidées ; accrocher quelqu'un est aussi valable qu'accrocher à quelqu'un (le pronom indique une réciprocité) => elles se sont accrochées